# Difficulty aligning JSONschema and XSD equivalent

Tags: xsd, jsonschema

I've got a problem, I can't solve on my own. So I'm trying to find help at StackOverflow.

I'm generating XSD and use a python-based converter to convert the XSD to JSON schema. The JSON schema is used to validate JSON code which I will not explain in detail. My problem is, that I have JSON code to validate which contains an array containing arrays (plural) containing integers.

The JSON-code looks like this:

```
"factors": [  
    [12,3], 
    [1,14]
]
```

I know how to write the JSON schema for this:

```
"factors": {
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/factorscontent"
    }, 
    "type": "array"
}

...

"factorscontent": {
    "items": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "type": "array",        
    "properties": {}
}
```

This works fine. But I don't know how to build this structure in XSD. Does anyone know how to face the "integer in arrays in array" problem?

One thing to add: If the json-code would look like this:

```
"factors": [ "items":{ [12,3], [1,14] } ]
```

I wouldn't have a problem because I could express the content of the "factors-array" as

```
<xs:element name="items" type="integer" max0occurs="unbounded"/>
```

But the array structure inside contains just integers, no elements!

Comment: One thing to add:

If the json-code would look like this: 
"factors": [ "items":{[12,3], [1,14]} ]
I wouldn't have a problem, because I could express the content of the "factors-array" as 
<xs:element name="items" type="integer" max0occurs="unbounded"/>

But the array structure inside contains just integer, no elements!

Comment: So your question could be rewritten as how to define a two-dimensional array in XSD.

Comment: Certainly your first Json structure is an int[][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid down voting, please cleanup your "would" JSON example, since `"factors": [ "items":{ [12,3], [1,14] } ]` is simply not well-formed JSON. A well-formed may look as below (of course, feel free to correct it so that it reflects what you've wanted, at least our tool would generate it the way it follows from the XSD snippet you've shared):

```
{
    "factors": [
        {
            "items": [ 12, 3 ]
        },
        {
            "items": [ 1, 14 ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Your question has an easy answer: there is no way to do it, unless you rely on proprietary markup in the XSD.

In XML, representing data requires some sort of markup; a text node and an attribute require an element to "hold" them. In XSD, you may use an `<xsd:list/>` to model an array of integers; even then, using it needs a(n) (repeating) element to make it an array of arrays (alternatively, the element may be wrapped in a repeating compositor, typically an `<xsd:sequence/>`).

Because of this must-have element, any converter that I know will automatically create objects (where *object* is as defined by JSON Schema Draft) and use the name of the element and/or attribute to create a *property*. Your array of arrays has no object, hence no property is allowed, therefore you cannot rely on core XSD constructs for this kind of conversion.

We've been doing XSD to JSD conversions for three years against real XSDs and so we've refined this conversion quite a bit. To achieve a scenario such as yours, we've defined a proprietary markup in an `<xsd:appinfo/>`: it instructs the conversion engine to skip creating a property and so, the associated object creation. I would recommend you change your Python based parser, so that it considers some sort of "hints", either the way we did it, or by authoring patterns (if you wish to apply them indiscriminately).

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed and helpful answer. I appreciate your effort. Because xsd and json schema are not that difficult to understand, I was already thinking of "it's maybe not working". So now I know.
And I think, the easiest way would be to change the python script for that specific issue, like you recommend.